# Using JS reduce, map or filter function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? My desired output is to create a new array out of the following object. If `supported === true`, add `id` to array. So in below object, the output should be `['CREDIT', 'DEBIT']`.

```
 const object = {
   "cardOptions": [
   {
      "id": "CREDIT",
      "supported": true
   },
   {
      "id": "DEBIT",
      "supported": true
   }
  ]
 }
```

Here is what I have now.

```
 const cardTypes = object.reduce((filtered, cardType) => {
      if (cardType.id && cardType.supportedAtLocation) {
          filtered.push(cardType.id)
      }
      return filtered
 }, [])
```

Comment: What is inefficient about this solution?

Comment: I'm wondering if reduce is the best method. Or if using map or filter is possible and better.

Comment: Reduce is the appropriate choice, cos you're filtering the array *and* creating a new data structure out of it. If you use @g2jose's method, it would work but then you're looping over the array twice. Reduce allows for one pass

Comment: You need `object.cardOptions.reduce` instead of `object.reduce` but that works. I'd personally go for `filter` + `map` but it is technically less optimal. Depending on your data, that might not matter, though and if you use something that allows lazy evaluation like Lodash, then you can change `object.cardOptions.filter().map()` with `_(object.cardOptions).filter().map()` and you'd avoid the double iteration. Ultimately, though [Eric Lippert said it best](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) - what is better and if it atters depends on circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use filter + map like this:

```js
object.cardOptions
  .filter(option => option.supported)
  .map(cardOption => cardOption.id)
```

Profiling this side by side using the [User Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API), at least on chrome, it seems like your `reduce` code is more efficient (but practically it probably won't matter unless you have a really large dataset).

Here's a quick higher order profiling function I often use:

```js
// A function to run an input function several times and profile performance using the User Timing API on chrome
const profile = (func, times) => (...args) => {
    const functionName = func.name;
    const trackName = `${functionName}`;
    const startTag = `${trackName}_start`;
    window.performance.mark(startTag);
    let results;
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i = i + 1)
        results = func(...args);
    const endTag = `${trackName}_end`;
    window.performance.mark(endTag);
    window.performance.measure(trackName, startTag, endTag);
    return results;
};
```

```js
const object = {
    cardOptions: [
        {
            id: 'CREDIT',
            supported: true,
        },
        {
            id: 'DEBIT',
            supported: true,
        },
    ],
};
const filterMap = () => {
    object.cardOptions
        .filter(option => option.supported)
        .map(cardOption => cardOption.id);
};
const reduce = () => {
    object.cardOptions.reduce((filtered, cardType) => {
        if (cardType.id && cardType.supported) {
            filtered.push(cardType.id);
        }
        return filtered;
    }, []);
};

profile(filterMap, 99999)();
profile(reduce, 99999)();
```

The output of the measure looks like so:

```js
window.performance.getEntriesByType('measure')

[
  {
    name: 'profileFilterMap',
    entryType: 'measure',
    startTime: 310637.6400000008,
    duration: 30.029999994440004, // higher duration for map + filter
  },
  {
    name: 'profileReduce',
    entryType: 'measure',
    startTime: 310667.7550000022,
    duration: 24.754999991273507, // reduce seems slightly more efficient
  },
]
```